# Template friend function of template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, declaration, friend

I am wondering how to make a function friend of a class and define the function outside class if the function's template arguments include but are not limited to the class's template arguments.

For example, I have the following template class and template friend function:

```
template<int N>  class Matrix;
template<typename T, int N> Matrix<N> operator*(const Matrix<N> &m1, const T &m2);

// class definition
template<int N>
class Matrix{
  template<typename T>
  friend Matrix<N> operator* (const Matrix<N> &m1, const T &m2);
};

// friend function definition
template<typename T, int N> Matrix<N> operator*(const Matrix<N> &m1, const T &m2)
{
    return m1; // just as an example
}
```

If I compile:

```
Matrix<3> m;
m * 1.0;
```

I would get the following linker error:

```
test.cc:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `Matrix<3> operator*<double>(Matrix<3> const&, double const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mismatch in kind.

Your initial declaration, and later definition, have this signature:

```
template<typename T, int N>
Matrix<N> operator*(const Matrix<N> &m1, const T &m2);
```

This is a function template taking *two* template parameters: `T` and `N`.

However, within your class, you make as a friend a function template that has this signature:

```
template<typename T>
friend Matrix<N> operator* (const Matrix<N> &m1, const T &m2);
```

This only has *one* template parameter: `T`. `N` is fixed here. This friend declaration also declares this function template. This is a better match, but not actually defined, hence the behavior you see.

---

You have two options I think.

1. Remove the namespace-scope declaration of `operator*` and just declare and define the friended `operator*` within the definition of `Matrix`.
2. Change the friend declaration to match the namespace-scope declaration:

   ```
   template<typename T, int M>
   friend Matrix<M> operator* (const Matrix<M> &m1, const T &m2);
   ```

(1) is the better option typically - doesn't involve adding more `operator*`s into global scope, which is good for compile times.

Comment: 3rd option: `template<typename T>
 Matrix<42> operator* (const Matrix<42> &m1, const T &m2) {/*..*/}` for every value ;-)